# Auto Weight Ignore tooth

Tags: weight-painting

I apply auto weight i think it look ok, but it not ok. My character tooth move without character.

[image]

Comment: do you mean the opposite? the teeth don't move? if so, you need to select the teeth in Edit mode and assign them to the good vertex group, the one with the name of the bone that is supposed to move them

Comment: I not sure what you mean select teeth. All character is one mesh.

Comment: go in Edit mode, put your mouse cursor over the teeth, press L to select, then in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, select the vertex group that they are supposed to be part of and press the Assign button